# Encryption based on a Minecraft world. Is it possible?

Tags: java, encryption, minecraft

So I was thinking of various techniques that you could use for encryption and I had an idea that you can use a Minecraft world to do the encryption for you.

So if you have a string, the program would go through each character and add the y-value of the corresponding position to the character.

For example, if you had the string "ABC", the program would move in a straight line and add the y-position of each index to each character, as demonstrated here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtSyM.jpg

Now, the string manipulation part is easy, but the part about getting the y-values through code is what really stumps me. I would presume Java would be best for this, but would I be able to write a bot that move through the world? How would I do this? Can I use macros or something like that? Or perhaps there is some way to export the map into an easily readable heightmap file.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this could be possible but would indefinitely take a whole lot of working, one thing that slightly concerns me with the (great) idea is the decryption of it, if it is based on the height of the player/terrain of the MineCraft 'world' you would need the very specific 'area of encryption' where you are for say; defining all the heights, so you are actually able to decrypt it back.

The most efficient way to get the y-position to be added to the character (if i am understanding correctly; like the Caesar Cipher) would be to somehow program a bot to move across the terrain and log the y-position every second/few seconds, you could do this by sending the movement keys to the actual MineCraft client which would probably have to be modified somewhat to support it, then use an array of the plaintext/message and slowly go through with the bot and add the y-position which would be a constantly changing variable depending on the height of the bot.